# Strategy for choosing lottery numbers when buying many tickets

Tags: probability

In a given lottery a user must choose 5 out of 50 numbers, without replacement. Prizes are offered for matching at least 2 of the winning numbers. If a user can purchase multiple tickets (let's say 10,000), which is not enough to significantly increase his odds of winning the first place prize (5/5 matches), what would be an optimal strategy of picking numbers to maximize the percentage of winning tickets, i.e. the number of tickets with at least 2 matching numbers?

My first attempt at this is to cycle through all the 3-tuples from the $﻿﻿﻿\binom{50}{3}$ combinations and add 2 random numbers to the 3-tuple to pick the numbers for each ticket. But each ticket's 5-tuple contains 10 3-tuples, so my approach is nowhere near optimal.

Comment: Do the numbers need to be in the correct place (i.e. if the winning number is 5,15,34,6,23, is 6,5,15,22,49 a '2-matcher')?

Comment: no, order is unimportant

Comment: What you are looking for is a [lottery wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lottery_wheeling). 

Since $10000\times {5 \choose 4}/{50 \choose 4} \approx 0.2$, while  $10000\times {5 \choose 3}/{50 \choose 3} \approx 5.1$, and $10000\times {5 \choose 2}/{50 \choose 2} \approx 81.6$, I would have thought that a sensible priority might be to avoid choosing sets of five which avoid having $4$ or $5$ elements in common with other sets and which minimise the number of cases of having $3$ in common with other sets.

Comment: that at least got me to the proper terminology for this type of problem - maximum coverage problem. and it's NP-hard: [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_coverage_problem)